# Load a PostgreSQL database using cloudconnect

Tags: postgresql, gooddata, cloud-connect

On the side of my Gooddata project, I maintain a small PostgreSQL database that contains a few tables.

I would like to be able to integrate both my ETL processes using the same tool, and it seems to me cloudconnect would be the easiest way, since I already have my whole GoodData ETL in it.

Here are the ways I tried to do it without success:

1. I tried to have a look in the documentation, and it seems to me that all the functionalities of CloverETL that enabled this (DBOutput, PostGreSQLDataWriter) are not available in Cloudconnect.
2. I managed to connect to the Agile Datawarehouse Service (Database attached to GoodData), but it seems that only the ADS database is able to understand the request:

   ```
   COPY MyDataBaseTable (field1,field2) FROM LOCAL '${DATA_TMP_DIR}/CIforADS.csv'
   ```

even when I adapt the syntax to PostgreSQL because the dynamic addressing I use here does not seem to work.

Is there any way to proceed that I'm missing? Can anyone think of a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

In general this could be achieved by using of "DBExecute" component, but 
I'm not sure if I understand it well - do you want to load data into your own Postgres instance using CloudConnect?